# mod_rewrite hid part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey guys, I did a bunch of google searching but I couldn't figure out how to get mod_rewrite working for my purpose.

Here is my url:

```
http://localhost/symfony2/web/index.php
```

I would like to hide the `web/index.php` section so that this:

```
http://localhost/symfony2/web/index.php/hello/bob
```

turns to this:

```
http://localhost/symfony2/hello/bob
```

Nothing seems to be working right now. It just keeps showing my folder structure. Here's what I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) localhost/symfony2/web/index.php$1 [L]
```

(Also posted at http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=31361.)

Comment: I copied the other post into this one. What have you tried so far? Please show your currently failing RewriteRule(s).

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/

RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/symfony2/web/index.php$1 [L]
Is what I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /symfony2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

(The `!-f` and `!-d` are to make sure that if there is a file or directory match it won't rewrite it.)